# Use jquery to apply a class if child is present

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, html-lists

I have a list that at times has more than one child. I'd like to style the parent if contains a number of children. I've tried a few options without success. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<ol class="parent">
    <li>
        <ol>
            <li>Something</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: if it contains multiple `li` or a `ol` containing an `ol`? And what is receiving the style modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to style the direct parent element, you can do this:

```
var $matches = $("ol > li > ol > li");
if($matches.length > 1) {
    $matches.parent().addClass("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($element.children('ol').length >= 2){
    $element has at least two 'ol's as children
}
```